# Displaying non-mhidden comments in chronological order

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments

When there are too many comments on a given answer the *overflow* is hidden which is quite understandable and great UI behaviour. However, those comments that are in view are not *always* in chronological order. This would not matter if all comments were directed at the answer but however; individuals comment on comments (*meta-commenting*) so that it reads like a conversation from top to bottom. The current strategy used doesn't guarantee that the *happens-before* comment will be seen in correct order.

I leave it to the meta-authorities to discuss if this is worth discussing (aka meta-discussing).

I should also add that comments show up in chronological order when you choose *show all comments*.

Comment: They are in chronological order, but there are comments that are between them.

Answer (score 4):

They are ordered chronologically -- look again!

Answer (score -1):

This is by design, they are shown ordered by votes until you expand it

Comment: They are not ordered by votes. They are ordered chronologically. The ones without votes are hidden.